# three.js CanvasRenderer - setting initial color for object together with transparency textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to use CanvasRenderer to render my object, which will change its textures on the runtime.
The texture are PNGs images with transparent background, and I want the background base color is of the face is set from the object.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980889/imageutils-loadtexture-with-callback-in-canvas-rendererr);) to get the texture successfully load and map into the object, but when I try to change the initial color of the object, I discover that the empty space of the object will remains transparent (and can see through into it) and do not have any base color that I am expecting.

The following is the code I use to make a trial on it:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./"+texture_url,new
THREE.UVMapping()); 

child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
                    {    
                          map: texture,  
                          transparent:false, 
                          opacity: 1
                    }); 

var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(245,210,179)");

child.material.color = color;
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

What would be the problem here?

**Editted**: Tried on the opacity attribute, but still no lucks in here. However, if removing the `map: texture` from the code, the object can show with the expected background color without any transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a limitation of `CanvasRenderer`.

You cannot apply a transparent texture and expect it to render as a decal -- that is, with the material color showing through.

You can have a color or a texture -- but not both.

The work-around is to modify your texture.

three.js r.63

Comment: I see. But I would know rather this a limitation of three.js itself or the non-webGL html5 canvas rendering? That means if using non-webGL approach apart from three.js's CanvasRenderer this issue will always still exist.

Comment: If you have questions about other approaches, you will have to make a new post. I can only comment on three.js.